# R: hist() not working on a simple vector

Tags: r, histogram

I have a simple vector for which I want to draw a histogram, but nothing happens,not even an error message.

Can you please tell me what I am missing?
Should I load a particular library?

here is my code:

```
vec2<-c(58213.00, -69212.89, -61613.13, 57082.20, 30111.00, 18621.05, 25832.42, 128175.36, 38134.85, 425313.57)
hist(vec2)
```

I even tried:

```
plot(vec2,type="h")
```

But nothing happens.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is working fine on my computer. Try `vec2 <- as.numeric(vec2)`. `hist(vec2)`.

Comment: http://www.mitchellenright.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/2014-02-08-Off-and-On-02.jpg

Comment: Incase you have a similar problem, try running: dev.off()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. Have your tried turning it off and on again?

If it doesn't work see if this results in a new file on your working directory

```
jpeg('histogramTest.jpg')
hist(vec2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: I closed R and restarted and it works now. Thanks!